# Passing an array of 'typedef struct' to a function

Tags: c, arrays, typedef

I have the following situation:

file A.c:

```
typedef struct element
{
    uint16_t value_raw;
    float value_scaled;
    char *desc;
} element;

element sv[REG_READ_COUNT];
```

file A.h:

```
typedef struct element element;
```

file B.c:

```
#include "A.h"
void dostuff (element sv[]) { }
```

at compile time I get
"error: array type has incomplete element type"
for the function argument definition in B.c.

What's the right way to do this?
How can I pass an array of type 'element' into a function?

Comment: Reproduced with gcc+clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5e314deef461290

Comment: FWIW, bcc32 6.70 also accepts `X *x` and rejects `X x[]`

Comment: Here is one question that was never asked of the OP and it actually makes a difference in how one can answer. There are actually 2 solutions. One involves properly using opaque (incomplete) types and one doesn't. Both are valid ways of solving the problem. If this was part of a homework assignment and it said you must use data hiding and create an abstraction around `element` then there is no answer given here that would be acceptable. If no data hiding was needed than the OPs choice of answer makes sense. So the simple question to remove all ambiguity is - Is data hiding `element` required?

Comment: The definition of the struct format should be in the .h file.  To have the instance of the struct visible everywhere, the instance declaration needs to be in the .h file.  In your code the instance declaration is in the .h file, but the struct format is missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `B.c`, `element` is an incomplete type (it is not defined in `A.h`, only in `A.c`). C disallows array declarators with incomplete element types (as you've discovered). Here's the relevant text from the C99 draft:

> ### 6.7.5.2 Array declarators
>
> #### Constraints
>
> 1. In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static`, the `[` and `]` may delimit an expression or `*`. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero. **The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type**. The optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static` shall appear only in a declaration of a function parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost array type derivation.

Emphasis mine. This applies to *all* array declarators, no matter where they occur: in variable declarations, typedefs, function parameter lists, etc.

To fix your code, put the full struct definition in `A.h`. Or, if `dostuff` doesn't actually need to work with the elements (e.g. simply to pass the "array" to some other function), you could use `void dostuff(element *sv)`.

Comment: @Deduplicator: An array is not a pointer. Declaring an array is illegal if the size of the elements is not known, AFAIK, but declaring a pointer to unknown elements is legal. Can you prove otherwise?

Comment: @nneonneo What he is saying is you cuold pass an array of pointers to element structures.

Comment: @Deduplicator There is no array of an unknown bound. There is a pointer to `element`.

Comment: @nneonneo To be clear, there is no array shown in `B.c`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Compare http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd7ef2def2aa7b11 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b1948967b35dfac

Comment: @juanchopanza That is an array of elements not an array of pointers to elements.

Comment: @Deduplicator That is interesting! Is it new in C11? Maybe what I said only applies in C89, in which case I take it all back!

Comment: @MichaelPetch The confusion is that a function parameter `T t[]` used to be equivalent to `T* t`. It still is in C++, but this might have changed in C.

Comment: Gcc refuses to compile `T t[]` with `-std=c89` and `-std=c99`. I'm confused, C11 (n1570) 6.7.6.3 p4 reads (in a "constraints" section): _After adjustment, the parameters in a parameter type list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function shall not have incomplete type._ As I understand it, this "after adjustment" refers to ibid. p7 _A declaration of a parameter as "array of type" shall be adjusted to "qualified pointer to type", [...]_ Interesting.

Comment: @mafso: Good find. clang+gcc,C89+99+11,pointer+array: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5e314deef461290

Comment: @juanchopanza : I never looked closely at his example. I think I see where all the confusion lies. I believe his example `element *sv` is wrong - would only allow you to access that pointer but arithmetic on the pointer wouldn't work like `sv++`. In my independent answer I was referring to an array of element pointers so I would have had `dostuff` being defined as `void dostuff(element *sv[])` .

Comment: @nneonneo: Did you look at 6.7.6.3 p4-7? Because there the standard flatly contradicts gcc and clang. Or explain how it does not.

Comment: @Deduplicator: OK folks, I have amended the answer. Your compilers are NOT wrong, the standard is quite clear that incomplete element types are simply illegal in array declarators.

Comment: @nneonneo bingo - thanks for finding it. I had stated in another comment that arrays have to be of complete types. The reason pointers to incomplete types work is because a pointer is complete in itself.

Comment: However I think your example has to be amended. dostuff(element *sv) is completely valid as a function prototype and should not produce errors. However it can't be used as an array. So try this (it should fail): `void dostuff(element *sv) { sv++; }` . This should fail because you are now using a pointer in array arithmetic and it should give a similar error as before. `sv++` in the example shouldn't work because to find the next element in the array it needs to know the size (because arrays need complete types to work on them this way)

Comment: @Deduplicator It seems the function signatures are considered equivlent, but have different requirements: http://ideone.com/cr20XL

Answer (score 2):

Minimal code to reproduce the error.

```
struct element;
void dostuff (struct element sv[]) { }
```

Testing on `clang` and `gcc` using coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5e314deef461290
Result: GCC and clang always complain about arguments of type array of incomplete type, and never about pointer to incomplete type.

Relevant standard-quotes:

> #### 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)
>
> [...]
>   4 After adjustment, the parameters in a parameter type list in a function declarator that is
>   part of a definition of that function shall not have incomplete type.
>   [...]
>   7 A declaration of a parameter as **‘‘array of type’’** shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
>   type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
>   array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
>   array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
>   actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many
>   elements as specified by the size expression.

Well, up to here it looks like array of incomplete type was perfectly fine for an argument type, even in a definition.

> #### 6.2.5 Types
>
> [...]
>   20 Any number of derived types can be constructed from the object and function types, as
>   follows:
>
> - An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a
>     particular member object type, called the element type. **The element type shall be
>     complete whenever the array type is specified.** Array types are characterized by their
>     element type and by the number of elements in the array. An array type is said to be
>     derived from its element type, and if its element type is T, the array type is sometimes
>     called ‘‘array of T’’. The construction of an array type from an element type is called
>     ‘‘array type derivation’’.

The above quote explicitly disallows using array-syntax with an incomplete type, for every case.

Conclusion: All those compilers seem to be right, even though that restriction seems unneeded.

---

Anyway, the proper course is not putting a forward-declaration for the type, but the declaration for the type itself into the header-file, unless it shall be an opaque type.

In that case, you will have to use pointer-syntax for the argument-type directly.

Answer (score 1):

As a secondary answer to provide a method to do what the OP wanted but assuming he needed data hiding, I present this code that builds on my first answer and provides generic access to an element type in one `C` file and providing only an opaque data type in the header file. Please note that to get a point across about what are pointers I use `element *` however they could have all been replaced by `ELEM_HANDLE` that I define as a type in the header. `ELEM_HANDLE` abstracts away the fact that we are dealing with element pointers. Since we use an opaque type we make available methods that can be called (defined in `element.h`) to work on our opaque type.

element.h:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct element element;
typedef element *ELEM_HANDLE;

extern element *element_new();
extern void element_delete(element *elem);
extern void element_set_value_raw(element *elem, uint16_t value_raw);
extern uint16_t element_get_value_raw(element *elem);
extern void element_set_value_scaled(element *elem, float value_scaled);
extern float element_get_value_scaled(element *elem);
extern void element_set_desc(element *elem, char *desc);
extern char *element_get_desc(element *elem);
```

element.c:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct element
{
        uint16_t value_raw;
        float value_scaled;
        char *desc;
} element;

element *element_new()
{
        return calloc(1, sizeof(element));
}

void element_delete(element *elem)
{
        free(elem);
}

void element_set_value_raw(element *elem, uint16_t value_raw)
{
        elem->value_raw = value_raw;
}
uint16_t element_get_value_raw(element *elem)
{
        return elem->value_raw;
}

void element_set_value_scaled(element *elem, float value_scaled)
{
        elem->value_scaled = value_scaled;
}

float element_get_value_scaled(element *elem)
{
        return elem->value_scaled;
}

void element_set_desc(element *elem, char *desc)
{
        elem->desc = desc;
}

char *element_get_desc(element *elem)
{
        return elem->desc;
}
```

testelem.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "element.h"

#define REG_READ_COUNT 2

void dostuff(element *sv[], int arrLen)
{
        int index;
        element *curelem;
        uint16_t raw;
        float scaled;
        char *desc;

        for (index = 0; index < arrLen ; index++){
                curelem = sv[index];
                raw = element_get_value_raw(curelem);
                scaled = element_get_value_scaled(curelem);
                desc = element_get_desc(curelem);
                /* Do more interesting stuff here */
                printf("%s, %d, %.4f\n", desc, raw, scaled);
        }
}

int main()
{
        unsigned int index;
        element *sv[REG_READ_COUNT]; /* array of element pointers*/
        char desc1[] = "The answer to everything";
        char desc2[] = "OtherStuff";

        /* Initialize an array of pointers to element items */
        for (index = 0; index < sizeof(sv) / sizeof(element *); index++)
                sv[index] = element_new();

        element_set_value_raw(sv[0], 42);
        element_set_value_scaled(sv[0], 6.66f);
        element_set_desc(sv[0], desc1);
        element_set_value_raw(sv[1], 123);
        element_set_value_scaled(sv[1], 456.7f);
        element_set_desc(sv[1], desc2);

        dostuff(sv, REG_READ_COUNT);

        /* free the array of pointers to element items*/
        for (index = 0; index < sizeof(sv) / sizeof(element *); index++)
                element_delete(sv[index]);

        return 0;
}
```

Note that I took liberties to pass in the array length to `dostuff` beside the array of element pointers. This provides dostuff with enough information to determine how many elements are in the array. This should compile (and run) properly on C89 or above and C++ compilers (provided you rename the `.c` files to `.cpp`).

I present this answer because using forward declarations and opaque types is how many "C" language shared objects are created.  This mechanism allows the element source to be compiled into an independent library or shared object and used without knowing what the `element` data type looks like. In essence we provide an interface contract between the modules that use us and the library. If we modify the internals of the structure element in `element.cpp` our modules that use it will not need to be recompiled (just re-linked). client code that uses the library would need to be rebuilt if we modify the interface(contract).

So in the end forward references (opaque types) can be used to hide `C` data type internals and provide a layer of abstraction. This type of mechanism is often used by shared objects (`.so` files) to build complex libraries that can be used by `C` programs.

Answer (score 0):

Because A.h only defines an opaque type `typedef struct element element` B.c can't possibly know the make up of element to even determine its size. So it can't create an array of those structures. If you want this code to work you would have to move the entire typedef in A.c to A.h . If you do this then there is no information hiding and the full structure is available through the header.

Additionally, You could create an array of pointers to structures (even though it may be incomplete) and pass it into your function but you wouldn't be able to access any of the structures member variables directly.

An example of using an opaque data type in arrays of pointers to those types:

```
typedef struct element element;
#define REG_READ_COUNT 100

void dostuff (element *sv[])
{
    sv++; /* get next pointer to element */
};

int main()
{
    element *sv[REG_READ_COUNT]; /* array of pointers to element */
    dostuff(sv);
}
```

This code is fine until it needs anything requiring the sizeof the actual type. We can't even initialize the data members to anything without extra glue code (another module) that actually does have access to the complete element type.

The reason you can have arrays of pointers (even to incomplete types) is because a pointer is a basic type in C. It is neither an incomplete type or a function type. A pointer has fixed size that the compiler can use to generate pointer arrays.

> **6.7.5.2 Array declarators**
>
> Constraints
>
> In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword static, the [ and ] may delimit an expression or *. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero. **The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type**. The optional type qualifiers and the keyword static shall appear only in a declaration of a function parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost array type derivation.

Because pointers are not incomplete types or function types you can create arrays of them even if they point to incomplete types. A pointer to an incomplete type doesn't make the pointer somehow incomplete. You just can't de-reference it and hope to do anything useful with it *directly*. I say directly because in data hiding techniques and opaque pointers you can provide indirect mechanisms to work with the opaque pointers data..

Here is an example of code that should fail to compile in a similar way the OPs did. We take the idea that pointers to incomplete types can be passed around (function arguments) but they still can't be used as an array inside a function:

```
typedef struct element element;
#define REG_READ_COUNT 100

void dostuff (element *sv) /* Completely legal but useless if you intend to use it as an array */
{
    sv++; /* This should fail - as we are doing array arithmetic on
           * an incomplete type. Can't find the starting point of the next
           * array element without knowing the size of the object */
};

int main()
{
    element sv[REG_READ_COUNT]; /* array of elements will also fail - size of object unknown */
    dostuff(sv);
}
```

This is nearly identical to the previous one. In this one we have a pointer `sv` to an incomplete type as a function argument (this is from nneonneo answer). This is completely legal since it is just a pointer. However attempting to do array arithmetic on it (using `++` in the body function) will fail because it needs to know the size of element and it isn't known. ++ and -- or to index an array are undefined behavior (and most standard compliant compilers will throw an error). ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 says:

> **6.3.2 Other operands**
>
> > 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
> >
> > > ...
> > >
> > > 2 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the unary & operator, the ++
> > >       operator, the -- operator, or the left operand of the . operator or an assignment operator,
> > >       an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated
> > >       object (and is no longer an lvalue). If the lvalue has qualified type, the value has the
> > >       unqualified version of the type of the lvalue; otherwise, the value has the type of the
> > >       lvalue. **If the lvalue has an incomplete type and does not have array type, the behavior is
> > >       undefined**

More on opaque types can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)

Comment: Where in `B.c` is any element of type `element` defined, quite aside from a whole array of them?

Comment: No not an array of elements. An array of pointers to elements. That can be done because the size of a pointer is known at compile time.

Comment: Please provide a standards quote that proofs the point. Compiler-errors happen...

Comment: I will find references to the standard. However you should note I didn't define dostuff as nneonneo suggested. There is a difference between his function prototype and mine. The reason this code works though is because at no point does my code need anything other than pointers to things. Pointers have a fixed size so it is completely legal.

Comment: Then prove that the extra indirection is neccessary to make it legal, and the compilers aren't in violation of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation error is described by Deduplicator's answer.

You can work around the issue by writing `element *sv`. However, `B.c` can only see the definition `typedef struct element element;`. It can't see what makes up the `element`.

If the "real" version of `dostuff` does anything with `sv` that requires knowing what that struct actually contains, then you need to move the definition of `struct element` from `A.c` into `A.h`.

Comment: Comment was: `that requires knowing what that struct actually contains`. That is true however it also entails any operation that needs to know the `size` of the object. If element was a **complete** type then argument `element *sv` allows one to do this: `sv++` to get to the next array element. If `element` is **incomplete** and the argument is `element *sv` then the programmer will be greeted with an error when he does `sv++`. This is because array arithmetic needs to know the size (even though it doesn't care about what makes up an `element`

Comment: The size of a struct is determined by its contents; there is no way to specify the size of a struct without having the full struct definition available. Therefore `sv++` requires knowing what the struct contains.

Comment: The compiler will take the type and determine its size from the contents up front. After that when it comes to doing the array arithmetic the contents don't matter but the size does. In theory if this were a union the contents cold be representative of many different things. The maximum size of the union + alignment will equal a size. But for array computation what is in it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MichaelPetch the size cannot be determined without knowing the contents . Array computation requires the contents to be visible.  If you disagree then please post a program where array computation is performed, but the contents are not visible.

Comment: The point you are missing is that the `size` is determined by the content. We both agree on that. The incomplete type the size is not known. However from the compilers perspective when doign array arithmetic it doesn't peek inside the structure anymore. It makes determination on size alone. It could be 100 chars or 25 4 byte ints. Array arithmetic doesn't care about the actual contents anymore. That is my point and the only clarification I was adding.

Comment: And I meant "it could be a *structure* of 100 chars or 25 4 byte ints". As long as it all adds up to 100 (in that example). I can cast between objects of 100 bytes(but different contents)do `pointer` arithmetic on both and it would yield the same result. It only matters about what is in those data structures at the time I try to access an element. Then I better be dealing with the right type.

Comment: I don't know what point you are trying to make.  In my post I say "anything that requires knowing what the struct actually contains". We agree that pointer arithmetic requires knowing the struct size, and knowing the struct size requires knowing the content. You seem to be saying "well the compiler could forget the content after it worked out the size". If so... so what? It required knowing what the struct contains at some point of the process of compiling the code that does pointer arithmetic.

Comment: What something CONTAINS is different than what its SIZE is. Here is an example where two structures with **different contents** that have the same size can pass off for one another **only** because they happen to be the same size (not what they *contain*). The link to the code is [here](http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/arrtest.c)

Comment: In what part is it undefined? Which statement. All are pointers to data structure (not member functions). Casting a data pointer from one type to the other is perfectly valid. The standard allow for all non function pointers to be cast. In this case the structures are the same size. And I would venture to guess if you used pedantic it would not see a problem.

Comment: @MichaelPetch `A` and `B` might have different alignment requirements. Casting a pointer to another type for which it is not aligned causes undefined behaviour.  Further, `A` or `B` might have trailing padding .

Comment: In any case, when your code does `arrB++`, *the full definition of `struct B` is visible*. You need to either post code that performs array arithmetic without having the full struct definition visible, or withdraw your claim that it does not matter what the full struct definition is.

Comment: You're overlooking transitivity of dependence. If X depends on Y, and Y depends on Z, then it is true that X depends on Z.  (In this case, X = pointer arithmetic, Y = element size, Z = element content).

Comment: My code comments did mention is what showing it being done with *complete* type not incomplete ones. You can't create one from incomplete types and I had an example of that in my first posted answer yesterday. The example was passing `element *sv` with incomplete type and then doing `sv++` which should produce an error. I was showing that the actual contents don't matter as long as the size is **known** and the size is the same (and there is no alignment issue).I did amend my sample at the link so the two types would have not one with stricter alignment than the other.C+11 I would used alignas

Comment: "complete type" is equivalent to knowing what the struct contents are, for a `struct`. "that the actual contents don't matter as long as the size is known" is a nonsense statement. The size cannot be known without also knowing the actual contents. The size is determined by the contents.

Comment: We are going to go in circles. So I will say this and that is the end. When it comes to **ARRAY** arithmetic the contents don't matter. Size matters (assuming proper alignment). The only thing we'll walk away with is the agreement that in order to calculate size that the contents matter. However once size is computed array arithmetic doesn't require any knowledge of the member variables of the structure.